# How to combine two tables based on a unique column that exists in both tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables in the same database. Both tables have a column with unique IDs which are exactly the same. How can I combine the tables to query a row in Laravel?

For example,

```
table 1
--------------------
| ID | val1 | val2 |
--------------------
| 1  |  a   |   b  |
--------------------
| 2  |  c   |   d  |
--------------------

table 2
-------------
| ID | val3 |
-------------
| 1  |  x   |
-------------
| 2  |  y   |
-------------
```

How can I query the above so it returns...

```
return query
---------------------------
| ID | val1 | val2 | val3 |
---------------------------
| 1  |  a   |   b  |   x  |
---------------------------
| 2  |  c   |   d  |   y  |
---------------------------
```

I'd like to know how to do this in with the Query Builder in Laravel.

Comment: Go look for "join" in the documentation. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DB::table('table1')->join('table2', 'table1.ID', '=', 'table2.ID')
    ->select('table1.ID', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
    ->get();
```

The `select()` part isn't necessary but if you remove it you get all the columns (in this case two times `ID`)

[Read the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)

Comment: What do you mean by two times ID?

Comment: Two times `ID` because normally a join selects all columns so you would get a result with `table1.ID` and `table2.ID`. Know what I mean?

Comment: Oh, I see. So there would be 2 columns with the IDs?

Comment: Yes exactly. You can try it out if you want. Just remove the `select()` line and use `print_r` to output the data...